# How is the help for Play Framework implemented?

Tags: playframework, chm

I am a huge fan of the [web-help used by the Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Home).  Here's why:

- Very easy to get docs for any version from the same place (all the way back to 1.0)
- All the docs have the same style (1.0 docs look just as good as 2.1.0 docs)
- Easy to read URLs (no iframe nonsense that many other web help systems seem to use)

I am currently using good old `.chm` for my application's documentation.  I'm in the process of building a `.chm` to website converter so that I can put the docs up online.

Before I get too far, does anyone know how the Play Framework web help system is implemented?  Is it possible to download the source somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is quite easy. Their documentation is near the source code in Git, so that they can benefit from Git (tag, merge/conflict).

It is written with Markdown so it is easy to write it with a simple text editor. Then it is converted to HTML files using the [Pegdown library](https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown).

For an example of this process, you can take a look at this project: https://github.com/ndeverge/play2-docs-renderer

It converts on the fly the Markdown file from the Github repo to HTML files.
You can see the result here: http://play2-docs-snapshot.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I'm especially interested in maintaining multiple versions of the documentation - 1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 2.0, etc.  Serving every single page of docs by running markdown through Pegdown seems unnecessarily expensive, but I'm very new to web dev and maybe it's not actually a big deal. (I love the play2-docs-renderer for looking at the bleeding-edge version, great idea).  Do you happen to know if the playframework.org site's docs are served form markdown for every page view?  I was planning on building something that was statically hosted from AWS, but maybe something dynamic would be fine.

Comment: AFAIK, the Play team generates the static doc once, at delivery, but I don't know how they do it. It should not be to complicated to use Pegdown to build your HTML files, and then to host it on AWS (or even S3 if it is static).

Answer (score 2):

I think they uses markdown, [here are the help sources](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/documentation/manual)

I don't know Play's documentation system details, anyway implementation something similar for my own app took about 2 hours with "editor" similar to this one used on the StackOverflow (javascript).

You can use for an example [markdownj](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.markdownj%7Cmarkdownj%7C0.3.0-1.0.2b4%7Cjar) lib for Java and [Pagedown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) as an editor.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they are very helpful!